# Linux Kernel Обработка исключения (Page fault)

Tags: c++, linux, c, исключения, kernel

Требуется написать модуль к ядру Linux, который перехватывает все исключения 14(Page Fault - #PF) в системе и считает их количество,а затем выводит это в логи.
   Может быть кто подскажет как именно прослушивать систему на вылеты исключений и ловить их (все это в ядре поэтому работают только библиотеки для работы с ядром). Как загружать модуль понятно, не ясен сам алгоритм поиска. И есть ли возможность использовать С++? 
Лучше без ассемблера, если есть возможность)

Comment: Посмотрите какие методы и механизмы используются для отладки менеджера памяти. Что-то мне подсказывает, что подобное уже есть (возможно не в том виде, в котором вам нужно, но уж точно база будет).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <linux/module.h>
// included for all kernel modules
#include <linux/kernel.h>
// included for KERN_INFO
#include <linux/init.h>
// included for __init and __exit macros

//Header to access memory stats
#include <linux/mm.h>

//Headers to write /proc file
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/seq_file.h>
#include <asm/vgtod.h>


MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Sh");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Number of pagefaults"); 

static int cpu_count = 0;

static int num_pagefaults_show(struct seq_file *m, void *v) {
    int cpu_num;

    int current_cpu = __getcpu();
    if(current_cpu + 1 > cpu_count) cpu_count = current_cpu + 1;//Update cpu count
    seq_printf(m, "+--------------------+\n");
    for(cpu_num = 0; cpu_num < cpu_count; cpu_num++)
        seq_printf(m, "| CPU %d | %10lu |\n",(cpu_num + 1),(unsigned long)per_cpu(vm_event_states.event[PGFAULT], cpu_num));//Print to file
    seq_printf(m, "+--------------------+");
    return 0;
}

static int num_pagefaults_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file) {
    return single_open(file, num_pagefaults_show, NULL);
}

static const struct file_operations num_pagefaults_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = num_pagefaults_open,
    .read = seq_read,
    .llseek = seq_lseek,
    .release = single_release,
};

static int __init num_pagefaults_init(void) {
  printk(KERN_ALERT "LOADED\n");    
  proc_create("num_pagefaults", 0, NULL, &num_pagefaults_fops); //Creates /proc entry
  return 0; // Non-zero return means that the module couldn't be loaded.
}

static void __exit num_pagefaults_exit(void) {
  printk(KERN_ALERT "UNLOADED\n");
  remove_proc_entry("num_pagefaults", NULL); //Removes /proc entry
} 

module_init(num_pagefaults_init);
module_exit(num_pagefaults_exit); 

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Можешь не благодарить.
Cчитает pf на каждом ядре.

Answer (score 4):

Вообще-то, это очень сложный и объёмный вопрос! Разумеется, ни о каком С++ речи быть не может. Весь API ядра написан на чистом C.

В самом общем виде, решение можно описать так:

1. Вы пишите модуль ядра, который в секции инициализации модуля регистрирует обработчик прерывания (linux/interrupt.h);
2. Кроме того, в модуле должна быть описана функция "нижней" половины, которая и будет делать всю полезную работу в режиме разрешённых прерываний ядра;
3. Функция, обрабатывающая прерывания, получив управление от ядра, собирает необходимую информацию и активирует отложенный запуск функции нижней половины. После чего просто завершается.

Где-то так... По каждому пункту можно написать с десяток страниц подробностей! Ну, к примеру, почитайте Олег Цилюрик, "Программирование модулей ядра Linux".

Comment: Не думаю, что это так, как вы описываете. Ваш метод для обычных драйверов устройств, вопрос же звучит про менеджер памяти и его потроха.

Comment: **вопрос же звучит про менеджер памяти** - на самом деле, вопрос звучит так: **Требуется написать модуль к ядру Linux**.  Или Вы предлагаете переписать системный менеджер памяти? Лично я не готов давать рекомендации в этом вопросе.

Comment: Вы принципиально путаете понятия **модуль** ядра и **драйвер**. Вы описываете второе, когда необходимо первое. Жаль, что у меня нет возможности заминусовать, так как ваш ответ не соответствует вопросу.

Comment: **Вы принципиально путаете понятия модуль ядра и драйвер.** - возможно.. И в чём, по Вашему мнению, разница ?

Comment: Модуль ядра не обязательно драйвер. И в данном случае как раз такое и требуется. Автор вопроса, вероятно, и сам "плавает" в теме, и по всей видимости, как и вы, не выполнил домашнего задания.

Comment: **вы, не выполнил домашнего задания** - значит, когда я пишу очередной драйвер использую в нём оператор "MODULE_DESCRIPTION(DRIVER_DESC);" - мне моё "домашнее задание" не засчитают? Ведь нельзя путать модули и драйверы! А если серьёзно, то хамство - не самый удачный способ доказательства правоты...

Comment: Не все даже драйверы должны использовать макросы `MODULE_*`. Речь про то, что обработка исключений Page Faults никакого отношения к *классическим драйверам устройств* не имеет. Ваш ответ по сути неверен. И уже на 5 день можно было и исправить.

Comment: **уже на 5 день можно было и исправит** - может быть проще не мне исправлять НЕПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ответ, а Вам написать ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ? Может быть достаточно холливаров разводить, а просто написать ответ ТС, а не мне ?

Answer (score 0):

Вот [здесь](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Dynamic_memory_allocation_example) что то похожее есть, но в userspace получение количества минорных и мажорных pf